# Find a certain character in a dataframe column & copy cell to another column

Tags: dataframe, copy, character

Find a certain character ($) in a dataframe column & copy cell to another column
It is is not working properly and I have tried almost everything for not finding the $ character.
If any $ character cell in NOT to be copied into  df2['TOTAL CHARGES2x']

for i in df2['TOTAL CHARGES1x']:
if searchfor in i :
print('no $ found - pass', i)
pass
else:
if searchfor not in df2['TOTAL CHARGES1x']:
df2['TOTAL CHARGES2x'] = df2.apply(lambda df2: df2['TOTAL CHARGES1x'] if searchfor not in df2['TOTAL CHARGES1x'] else df2['TOTAL CHARGES1x'], axis=1)
print('YES,  $ found - not pass',i)
else:
pass

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL CHARGES1x': ['$100', '200', '$300', '400']})
for i, value in enumerate(df2['TOTAL CHARGES1x']):
    if '$' not in value:
        df2.at[i, 'TOTAL CHARGES2x'] = value
    else:
        print('YES, $ found - not pass', value)

print(df2)
```

Comment: I have question when I try with the actual generated dataframe i get a blank.  Not using your df2.  what should I be doing in that case.

Comment: Can you show me the whole code?

Comment: Your code does work but I went a different route with using REGEX.  No need I abandon this approach.